# Ionic Ion-scroll vertical scrolling not working with Android 4.2.2

Tags: html, css, angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework

I am developing an ionic app in which i am using vertical scroll on dynamic tabs. Its working fine with browser and android version 4.2.2 + but not with 4.2.2 and less. Is it some kind of a bug? Anyone?

Comment: check the `android:targetSdkVersion` in Androidmanifest.xml file from which version it should work

Comment: try `minSdkVersion="10"` and check it below android < 4.2.2